# MySQL master-slave replication with more than 1 server

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

Is it possible to setup replication for database_A from master_A and database_B from master_B server? It looks like I can only set one master-host in MySQL configuration file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps you want to reformulate your question a little bit, so you want your database master server to replicate to 2 database slave servers ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL master-master-replication as master for master-slave-replication](http://serverfault.com/questions/161741/mysql-master-master-replication-as-master-for-master-slave-replication)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this tread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?28,359715,359715#msg-359715) and [this article](http://shinguz.blogspot.com/2008/10/mysql-multi-master-single-slave.html).

A possible trick is [federated storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html), but is not good as replication.